# Can't access share drive on windows machine from Python

Tags: python, smb

I have a windows machine with a server name 'HPTOUCH'. I also have a share directory called 'Movies' on this windows machine.  In raspian rasp pi using python 2.7, I am writing a simple test program to access the windows directory from the Pi.  I've tried all the suggestions here, i.e.

```
    os.listdir(r'\\HPTOUCH\Movies')
    os.listdir('\\\\HPTOUCH\\Movies')
    os.listdir(r'\\192.168.1.103\Movies')
    os.listdir('////HPTOUCH//Movies')
    os.listdir(r'\\smb://HPTOUCH//Movies')
```

Well, you get the idea. I keep getting an error: No such file or directory.  What am I doing wrong.  If I am in XBMC, I can easily access any movie on that drive, so permissions seem to be OK. What is the python code for accessing a windows share?

Comment: Have you tried 'smb://HPTOUCH//Movies'

Comment: @mksteve Yes, and many others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux (under XBMC) doesn't support UNC style paths. You either have to mount the remote filesystem first, use an existing mount point or use https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/ library.

To mount your remote server:

```
smbmount //192.168..103/Movies /mnt/movies –o "username=Tony,password=mypass"
```

Comment: As a newbie, I have no idea how to mount the share drive, or where to mount it to.  I tried sudo mount -t 192.168.1.103:Movies -o username=Tony, password=mypass, workgroup=WORKGROUP  but that didn't work.  How hard could it be to get a dir list of a share directory from a raspian raspberry pi?  HARD

Comment: It's not supposed to be easy ;) Your command is wrong though. See http://www.linuxnix.com/2009/09/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux.html

Comment: that is where I got the command in the first place.  Guess its just not for me to list as dir from a windows share.  I give up, scrapping the project. going home.

Comment: Have another look at your command before you give up - it's got about 3 syntax errors. You might find `smbmount` easier to work with or use the library I linked to.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to tell me how the command should look like, since all the components you may need are already here.

Comment: @TonySprings You don't have a great history of accepting or upvoting good answers. Please do some house keeping on past and present questions. Cheers.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for why accepting is beneficial to you also :)

Comment: I was not aware of the upvoting and accepting procedures.  I have gone back and tried to correct all of my mistakes. Your link explained everything...

Comment: Cheers Tony. Please see the updated answer with the required command

Comment: So sad that it didn't work.  I get this error: -bash: smbmount: command not found.

Comment: if I use mount instead of smbmount, I get this error: mount error(13): Permission denied.  All the shares have 'everyone full permission'  so what permission are they wanting , and where can I set it?

Comment: Try `mount -t smbfs -o "username=Tony,password=mypass" 192.168.1.103:/Movies /mnt/movies`

Comment: You need to run mount as root

Comment: yes, I put sudo in front of everything I do.  Using mount, I get this error: mount: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'

Comment: Ah, they've migrated to cifs. Use: `mount -t cifs -o "username=Tony,password=mypass" 192.168.1.103:/Movies /mnt/movies`. You may need to install cifs-utils: `apt-get install cifs-util`

Comment: that worked, now I can see the /home/pi directory in the windows file explorer. But when I try to access the windows hard drive from raspian, I get 'no file or directory' error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91254/discussion-between-alastair-mccormack-and-tony-springs).